# Plotly express setting height of a specific subplot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-express

How can I set an height of a specific subplot, which made by facet_row.

```
import plotly.express as px 
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.DataFrame([dict(team='Wolfs',start='2004-05-23',end='2006-05-24',country='Russia'), 
dict(team='Lions',start='2007-07-05',end='2009-07-06',country='USA'), 
dict(team='Crows',start='2001-08-9',end='2003-08-11',country='USA'), 
dict(team='Elephants',start='2010-02-14',end='2012-02-15',country='China') ])
fig=px.timeline(df,x_start='start',x_end='end',y='team',facet_row='country')
fig.show()
```

As a start, I want to make china's row height 2x bigger than others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `plotly.express` can directly change the height of each facet graph. In plotly, the plotting area of a graph is managed by a setting called domain.

```
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start='start', x_end='end', y='team', facet_row='country')
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(domain=[0, 0.4]), 
                  yaxis2=dict(domain=[0.5, 0.7]),
                  yaxis3=dict(domain=[0.8, 1.0]))
fig.update_layout(height=450)
fig.show()
```

[image]